# How to guarantee JMS reliable delivery

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms

I think plenty of (Spring in my case) applications using JMS may follow this workflow:

```
Database A ===> Producer ===> JMS Queue ===> Consumer ===> Database B
```

then reliability is a concern. Let's say if when a data record in `Database A` should always be marked as `delivered`, when the message contains the data record is truely consumed and persist the data in `Database B`. Then there are questions:

1. From my knowledge, currently JMS protocol does not define any functions to send acknowledgement from `consumer` to `producer`, but only to `MOM`, so the actual `consumer-to-producer` acknowledgement methods vary by JMS provider. So does it mean there is no way to develop a mechanism for such acknowledgement that can work for generally all JMS products(ActiveMQ, WebSphere MQ and Jboss MQ)?
2. Consider the scenario of a blackout, then does it make the messages in the queue just evaporate so need to resend? or different JMS products can pick up what is left, as the messages are Serialized, so that missing message can be only caused by transaction management or async/sync configuration but not because of application server is down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS guarantees the delivery of the message by nature, if the message is posted, then it will delivered to a consumer if there is one, whatever happen, the MOM is designed to ensure this fact. Anyway, delivered does not necessary mean processed.

Reliability is ensured by various mechanism :

- the first one is the persistence of message in the queue (the queue AND the message must be flagged as persistent, which is the default value) which ensure that message will not be lost in case of system interruption.
- then you have the acknowledgement and the retry policy, message will be kept in the queue until consumer acknowledge it and in case of transacted session, will be redelivered until consumer effectively processed the message or max retry is reached. Failed message can then be redirected to a dead letter queue for analysis.

To ensure the coherency between the two datasources you have to use XA transaction at least on the producer side (you have at least 2 resources implied in the transaction database A and JMS queue) in order to guarantee that the message will not be posted to the queue if the commit in database A fails or the database will not be updated if the post to the queue fails. Message consumption should be transacted too to ensure redelivery in case of rollback.

The transaction boundaries will never include both consumer and producer because it conflicts with the asynchronous nature of the messaging system, you can't afford to lock the resources on the producer side until the consumer process the message because you have no guarantee on when it will happen.

NB : in the event that your database does not support XA (or to improve performance) and if you have only 2 resources implied in the transaction (database and JMS queue) you can have a look to [Logging Last Resource Transaction Optimization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jta/llr.html)

Answer (score 2):

1) From my experience with queue managers (MQ Series, ActiveMQ and HornetQ) I never needed this kind of acknowledgement between producer/consumer. Also the environment that I used to deal with, the traffic was about 50/60 million per day of objects on several queues. And the queues are all persisted as well.

2) In my case, using the persistence mechanism on queue manager was totally sufficient to handle a blackout scenario. I used disk persistence on MQ Series and HornetQ.

However, sometimes to ack the amount of messages, we developed some mechanisms to compare Database A with Database B, to be sure that messages were consumed as well. I don't know if JMS architecture should provide this kind of mechanism, because such task could decrease the performance.

It's something - in my point of view - that you have to measure on your system architecture how important is to match this information, because it's not that easy to keep.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess the `blackout` tolerance is provided by the application servers(Websphere, WebLogic, Jboss...), how about ActiveMQ so that the application can be reliable by its own?

Comment: I think you can check on ActiveMQ docs, on persistence section (http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html). Since version 4.1 you can setup persistence feature using disk or database. I never used on this queue manager, but I know that's possible. :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have to keep the question open for a while to invite more opinions, but your idea is precious :)

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad to help. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this seems like a case for JTA/XA transactions (as long as your DB/JMS vendors support them).  Spring TX managers can help make the tx management (more) vendor agnostic.

FYI, I use Apache Camel for this type of flow which has pretty good error handling across producers/consumers.

Comment: JTA means Java transaction API, it's just a JSR on transaction management in Java and RDBMS / MQ vendor support is not relevant. I suppose that you wanted to say XA (multiple resource distributed transaction) Note that JMS is also a java ee JSR and so all implementation are xa compliant (if not they are not providing a JMS implementation but a simple messaging one)

Comment: moreover transaction are NEVER distributed across mom boundaries (producer and consumer) because it conflicts with the messaging asynchronous nature of MOMs. Producing a message may be transactional and consuming one also but they will never be part of the same transaction.

Comment: Yes, JTA/XA, thanks.  I think we have different definitions of MOM.  Some (like activemq) implement the JMS API and support XA transactions, but some (like rabbitmq) do not implement the JMS API and do not support global transactions.  Of course plenty of DBs (and DB drivers) do not support XA.  My point was that a global transaction should be able to let the producer know that the consumer was/was not successful (and that the Spring tx manager can help).

Comment: the same does IBM Business Automation Workflow or App Connect Enterprise.